# R: Concatenating a string to every column in a row (excluding col 1, variable col length, the string is held in col 1 of each row)

Tags: r, dataframe, concatenation, apply, lapply

I have a Tab delimited file with multiple lines/rows, and each line contains a variable amount of columns:

```
Name1 String111 String112 NA        NA
Name2 String121 String122 String123 NA
Name3 String131 String132 String133 String134
```

And so on and so forth (no pattern as to what line has how many entries). I would like to add the name in the first column to the beginning of every occupied (!= NA) column in that line/row such that I end up with:

```
Name1 Name1String111 Name1String112 NA             NA
Name2 Name2String121 Name2String122 Name2String123 NA
Name3 Name3String131 Name3String132 Name3String133 Name3String134
```

My attempt The limit of my capacity is changing the value of a single column across all rows:

```
Table$X2 <- paste(Table$X1, Table$X2)
```

My shot at then getting to work for all columns:

```
NewTable <- lapply(2:nrow(Table), 
function (x) get(paste0("Table$X", x )) <-  paste(Table$X1, " ", get(paste0("Table$X", x )))
)
```

In the end my goal will be to have a /n delimited list of variables associated with a set of names.

For example, if I want (Name1, Name2) in the end I would have:

```
Name1String111 
Name1String112
Name2String121 
Name2String122 
Name2String123
```

My plan is to use the table I create from this question remove the first column, then transpose all the remaining columns into rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `lapply` to iterate over each column and paste `V1` column to them.

```
df[-1] <- lapply(df[-1], function(x) stringr::str_c(df$V1, x))
df
#     V1             V2             V3             V4             V5
#1 Name1 Name1String111 Name1String112           <NA>           <NA>
#2 Name2 Name2String121 Name2String122 Name2String123           <NA>
#3 Name3 Name3String131 Name3String132 Name3String133 Name3String134
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = c("Name1", "Name2", "Name3"), V2 = c("String111", 
"String121", "String131"), V3 = c("String112", "String122", "String132"
), V4 = c(NA, "String123", "String133"), V5 = c(NA, NA, "String134")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: wait a second, in the apply function, how are columns being stored/targeted in x?  could someone be so kind to explain.
maybe @Ronak Shah
thank you so much by the way

Comment: I would expect x to pass either all the rows OR all the column but how does it go column by column for each row

Comment: `lapply` works column-wise. It works for complete column at a given time. So for first iteration it is column 2, then column 3 and so on till the last column. I use `-1` to ignore the 1st column @SkyScraper

Answer (score 1):

Mutate across the columns that are not V1 and concatenate V1 to the value in the current column.

```
text="Name1 String111 String112 NA        NA
Name2 String121 String122 String123 NA
Name3 String131 String132 String133 String134"

df=read.table(text=text, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
mutate(df, across(-V1, ~str_c(V1, .)))

     V1             V2             V3             V4             V5
1 Name1 Name1String111 Name1String112           <NA>           <NA>
2 Name2 Name2String121 Name2String122 Name2String123           <NA>
3 Name3 Name3String131 Name3String132 Name3String133 Name3String134
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with a combination of function of the `tidyverse`. Each step will be *piped* into the next one.

1. Defining data and loading the `tidyverse`

```r
library(tidyverse)

my_data <-
  structure(
    list(
      col1 = c("Name1", "Name2", "Name3"),
      col2 = c("String111", "String121", "String131"),
      col3 = c("String112", "String122", "String132"),
      col4 = c(NA, "String123", "String133"),
      col5 = c(NA, NA, "String134")
    ),
    row.names = c(NA, -3L),
    class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")
  )

my_data
#> # A tibble: 3 x 5
#>   col1  col2      col3      col4      col5     
#>   <chr> <chr>     <chr>     <chr>     <chr>    
#> 1 Name1 String111 String112 <NA>      <NA>     
#> 2 Name2 String121 String122 String123 <NA>     
#> 3 Name3 String131 String132 String133 String134
```

2. `mutate()` across all columns except the first one. The function pastes the first column to every value with exception of the `NA`s.

```r
my_data %>% 
  mutate(across(-col1, ~if_else(!is.na(.x), paste0(col1, .x), .x)))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 5
#>   col1  col2           col3           col4           col5          
#>   <chr> <chr>          <chr>          <chr>          <chr>         
#> 1 Name1 Name1String111 Name1String112 <NA>           <NA>          
#> 2 Name2 Name2String121 Name2String122 Name2String123 <NA>          
#> 3 Name3 Name3String131 Name3String132 Name3String133 Name3String134
```

3. Get rid of the first column

```r
my_data %>% 
  mutate(across(-col1, ~if_else(!is.na(.x), paste0(col1, .x), .x))) %>% 
  select(-col1)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#>   col2           col3           col4           col5          
#>   <chr>          <chr>          <chr>          <chr>         
#> 1 Name1String111 Name1String112 <NA>           <NA>          
#> 2 Name2String121 Name2String122 Name2String123 <NA>          
#> 3 Name3String131 Name3String132 Name3String133 Name3String134
```

4. Transpose or *pivot* the data in a longer format, so every observation has its own row. Note that this also generates a column indicating the name of the previous column. You can use `values_drop_na = TRUE` to get rid of the `NA`s.

```r
my_data %>% 
  mutate(across(-col1, ~if_else(!is.na(.x), paste0(col1, .x), .x))) %>% 
  select(-col1) %>% 
  pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = "column", values_to = "string", values_drop_na = TRUE)
#> # A tibble: 9 x 2
#>   column string        
#>   <chr>  <chr>         
#> 1 col2   Name1String111
#> 2 col3   Name1String112
#> 3 col2   Name2String121
#> 4 col3   Name2String122
#> 5 col4   Name2String123
#> 6 col2   Name3String131
#> 7 col3   Name3String132
#> 8 col4   Name3String133
#> 9 col5   Name3String134
```

5. Get rid of the `column` column.

```r
my_data %>% 
  mutate(across(-col1, ~if_else(!is.na(.x), paste0(col1, .x), .x))) %>% 
  select(-col1) %>% 
  pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = "column", values_to = "string", values_drop_na = TRUE) %>% 
  select(-column)
#> # A tibble: 9 x 1
#>   string        
#>   <chr>         
#> 1 Name1String111
#> 2 Name1String112
#> 3 Name2String121
#> 4 Name2String122
#> 5 Name2String123
#> 6 Name3String131
#> 7 Name3String132
#> 8 Name3String133
#> 9 Name3String134
```

Last, assign a name to the result so you can store it how you want.

```r
result <- my_data %>% 
  mutate(across(-col1, ~if_else(!is.na(.x), paste0(col1, .x), .x))) %>% 
  select(-col1) %>% 
  pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = "column", values_to = "string", values_drop_na = TRUE) %>% 
  select(-column)
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: In the `if_else` why did you predicate it with `~`?

Comment: and what is the `.x` you are using?

Comment: everything else makes sense! thats much!

Comment: In that example, `across()` takes 2 arguments. The first one is a selection of columns, with `-col1` I'm asking for all columns excluding the first one. The second argument is a function to apply  across al the selected columns, it can have the form of a purrr style lambda function where `~.x +1` is the same as `function(x) x +1`. Check `across()`s [documentation](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/across.html) for more details.

Comment: Thank you! First time hearing about a purrr style lambda function so I have a lot to learn!

Comment: I am having trouble finding information on `~`
You can put it in front of any function and it will cause that function to iterate `function(x) x +1` ? 

sorry sorry thank you thank you

Comment: an additional one if you have a sec, but why doesnt 
`mutate(across(-X1, function(x) {if_else(!is.na(x), paste0(X1, " ", x), x)}))`
work if across should feed all the columns to x?

Comment: Thank you again for your response ^-^, learning/learned a lot for your response and it contained a great answer to my pivoting question but the answer provided by Ronak for the primary question is more elegant of a solution.